# how can i provide a file for upload by default if user does not upload any, m using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

how can i provide a file for upload (say from database) by default for the upload class in codeignitor, if user does not upload any the default file should be considered, m using codeigniter.

Help appreciated. :)

Comment: why would you want to run the upload process even when no file selected by user to upload....you could always use a default image if no file is uploaded by user and that wont require uploading default file

Comment: Why would you upload a file for a user if the user doesn't?

Comment: well the process is for edit functionality. when a user wants to edit the form all other details are shown by default so that if he wants to change only some part he can do that easily. But i am not able to show him the file he uploaded. In order to make user effort less i am trying this.

Comment: In your controller, just check if the file input field is empty and if it is, just use the image that he already has uploaded.

Comment: Another option is to check the $_FILES superglobal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna explain to you based on a user profile module for example.

Put a default image in your upload folder, let's say

```
/www/uploads/images/no-avatar.png
```

On your controller, you can do something like this :

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')) // <input name="image" ... />
{
      $user['image'] = 'no-avatar.png';
}
else
{
      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

      $user['image'] = $data['file_name'];
 }

 // then you store the value in the database
```

Simply put, all users have the same default avatar, if they upload their own, the latter will override the default one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the solution i wanted. :)

Comment: I don't have that much of reputation points for an up vote but sure as soon as i get, I will be happy to upvote. :)